# Recursively disable child widgets mouse wheel events

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QListWidget which contains some custom complex widgets. Those widgets contain child widgets which the QListWidget does not have access to. However, some of those latter widgets are QComboBoxes, and they grab the mouse wheel event for them, instead of sccrolling through the list.

I'm looking for a way to disable that sort of grabbing, so that the list can be scrolled from anywhere on the list without worries that it'll change something else. All solutions I can find work from the child (either installing events filters, or subclassing), but I don't have access to that.

**Is there any way to do it just from the parent?**

I'd search for the children and install the filters, but the number of layers is unknown.

Comment: If you want to break out the big hammer, you can override QApplication::notify(QObject*,QEvent*) in your qApp object (you'll need to subclass QApplication, obviously) and intercept/redirect any calls where the QObject turns out to be one of the QComboBoxes inside your QListWidget.

Comment: Wow, that's a bit too big. But good to know about it, anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think event filters is actually the right way to go, assuming, that is, that you want all of the descendant QComboBox objects to ignore wheel events. You can use QObject::findChildren  on the parent widgets, which will recursively give you all the QComboBox descendants, no matter how many levels down. Then create a simple event filter that blocks wheel events and install that event filter on those children.

The code would be something like:

```
WheelBlocker *filter = new WheelBlocker ();
QList <QComboBox *> cblist = parent->findChildren <QComboBox *> ();

for (int i = 0; i < cblist.count(); i++)
{
    cblist[i]->installEventFilter (filter);
}
```

If there's some reason you don't want all descendant combo boxes to behave this way and don't have any mechanism for identifying them, then this can't work. Otherwise, it should be fine, and it's pretty simple. You'd still need to write the WheelBlocker class, or you can make whatever class this is being done in the event filter. Either way is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Yeah, this ended up being a terrible question. But I never would've guessed that findChildren was recursive. But for the widgets to respond to those events when selected I had to add `cblist[i]->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);` which I found [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/25072/how-to-ignore-the-mouse-wheel-event-when-combo-box-is-not-in-focus/4). (It's not in the question though, it's just some extra info)

Comment: Good to know and glad it helped.